# change label in custom python pyside widget

Tags: python, pyside

The image attached shows the custom widget i'm creating for a larger project. The first widget consists of

- label
- textedit
- listwidget

I then take this custom widget and create two instances of it in my new second widget. I want to change the label of each instance to something unique. The goal being to have one widget labeled 'Teams' and the other 'Members'. How do i make it possible for me to change the label of each instance of the initial custom widget?

**Current UI**

[image]

**Target UI**

[image]

the goods...

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
In this example, we create a custom widget.

authors:
website: JokerMartini.com
"""

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class NameListWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(NameListWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self): 

        # formatting 
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Input List')

        # widgets
        self.listLabel = QtGui.QLabel("Label")
        self.nameInput = QtGui.QLineEdit()
        self.nameList = QtGui.QListWidget()

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listLabel)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.nameInput)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.nameList)
        self.show()


class FactionWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(FactionWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self): 

        # formatting 
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Teams')

        # widgets
        self.sportsListWidget = NameListWidget()
        self.memebersListWidget = NameListWidget()

        # layout
        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self)
        self.mainLayout.setSpacing(10)
        self.mainLayout.setContentsMargins(10,10,10,10)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.sportsListWidget)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.memebersListWidget)
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = FactionWidget()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set it directly from your instance:

```
ex.sportsListWidget.listLabel.setText('Teams')
ex.memebersListWidget.listLabel.setText('Members')
```

Or your `NameListWidget`'s constructor method can include a string parameter that will set the label on its creation. (This should be the better approach)

```
class NameListWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title):
        super(NameListWidget, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()
        self.listLabel.setText(title)
```

Then when you're adding them in `FactionWidget`:

```
# widgets
self.sportsListWidget = NameListWidget('Teams')
self.memebersListWidget = NameListWidget('Members')
```

Is this what you're after?